# How to get access into an encrypted home directory with a simple (or not) command via a LiveUSB?

Tags: boot, command-line, live-usb

I am using a LiveUSB and I need to get access to my files on an encrypted /home/ directory, because I was way too dumb to not think about a situation like this. (Ubuntu getting destroyed)

I need a command which I can simply copy paste at the terminal and get access to my encrypted files, and copy paste them at an external drive, just with than 10- commands? (If possible)

Comment: Do the instructions [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/116297/) help?

Comment: Ironically, after googling my matter a bit more, I found that article. Yes it does help, but I got 2 questions. Can you make all of this problem be solved with only 1 command? This is what I am trying to find.

Of course I will follow that tutorial to fix my problem!

Comment: Sadly I can't imagine there's any magical one-liner.  I'm happy to be proven wrong, but I honestly doubt it. :)  Until someone writes the "readMyMind" command, I suspect you're stuck with it, sorry :)

Comment: You can make multiple commands in one with "|" can't you?